# Problems styling a navigation menu active tab HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css, navigation

I am having a bit of trouble styling a navigation menu where you can select packages.

This is going to be a nav menu for a mobile website.

The active green li tab I need to be evenly spaced across the full with of the ul

My problem is when I click on the tab to make it active the green doesnt fill up all the li and blue is still visible.

Secondly on the green active tab li I need to display a down arrow at the bottom center of the active tab.

I have included a fiddle with it more or less done, just need help with styling it to finish it off.

http://jsfiddle.net/8C3U3/

```
<ul id="navlist">
   <li><a href='#' class="m-active">Basic</a></li>
   <li class="spacer"><a  class="m-active"href='#'>Standard</a></li>
   <li><a  class="m-active"href='#'>Premium</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: The reason for the <li> still showing blue is due to the padding style you have on the <li> element. You don't need padding on both the <li> and the <a> tag.

Comment: I want to solve this, but it's really not clear in your question what you want done.

Comment: Hi, the active tab (green), i want it to fill the entire <li>. The 3 li's i want evenly spaced out and centered. Finally on the active <li> i want a down arrow positioned at the bottom center of the <li> to indicate you are pointing at a certain package? hope that makes sense? cheers :-)

Comment: so each <li> has the exact same width and is centered, and the active tab the whole <li> is green with an arrow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## I. Why does the blue still display?

The blue still displays for a few reasons. I'll go through each of them.

1. The first reason is that you've given your `li`s padding and a blue background color. Yet you assign the green background color to your `a`s. Since the `a` is contained within the `li`, and the `li` has padding, the `a` couldn't possibly extend the full dimensions of the `li` and cover up the blue. [View this JSFiddle, where that problem is corrected.](http://jsfiddle.net/8C3U3/2/)
2. The second reason is that your `li`s are set to be inline elements. Inline elements interpret all whitespace in your code (spacebar spaces, new lines, etc.) as a single space between the elements. To get rid of that spacing, get rid of the whitespace between the elements *in the code itself*. [View that here.](http://jsfiddle.net/8C3U3/3/)

Unsolved questions: You'll see that there's still blue visible. This is because borders are rendered outside of the element, and this border doesn't extend the whole height of your `li` (let alone the `ul`, which also has a blue background set). You'll need to figure out how to handle this. One option is that you could use `:before` and `:after` pseudoelement so that the spacing between the elements is closed.

## II. Making an arrow beneath the active tab

The way I usually make arrows is with an `:after` pseudoelement. Here are the steps:

1. We want to position the arrow as we want, which is best done by setting it to `position: absolute;`. To make it relative to the parent, we need to explicitly define the position on the parent. So let's go with `position: relative;`, as that won't change the location of the parent. Now we can move the arrow around wherever we want!
2. Let's set the pseudoelement to be `display: block`; and give it empty content. This makes it display as we want it to.
3. You can either use the border hack to create the triangle, or use the unicode triangle down character. I chose to use that [in this JSFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/8C3U3/4/)

Unsolved questions: Right now, your `li`s aren't the same width. This means that no single line of CSS code could center the triangles for all of the `li`s. You either need to set the `li`s to be the same width, then position the triangle, or target each `li` individually and manually place the triangle based on the width. I suggest the former of these two possibilities.

## III. How I'd Do It

And [here's how I'd make the menu](http://jsfiddle.net/6XUyT/), with most of the issues above resolved. Maybe this will be a place for you to work from.

If you're not planning on fading the arrow in, then you might prefer to use the [border hack to create the triangle](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-triangle/), which has deeper browser support.

Comment: wow thanks for the detail!! :-) problem solved, one quick thing, is it possible to center the menu so its in the middle of the blue <ul>?

Comment: `+1` Perfect description. However it's better to: make width of `a` elements to `auto`, position it to `relative` and set the `left` arrow to `50%` with some negative margin ([FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mojtaba/6XUyT/2/)).

Comment: how would you center the li's in the middle of the menu?

Comment: That's a good suggestion, @NOX! My avoidance of solutions like that -- those that use negative margin to correct for spacing -- is that users with browser zoom other than 100% might not see it displayed properly.

Comment: cant seem to get the triangle working, in the fiddle its showing a shape symbol?

Comment: Yes, it's using the [BLACK DOWN-POINTING TRIANGLE unicode character](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/25bc/index.htm). If you just copy+paste it, it should display in all browsers with potential for IE trouble. If you specify a unicode font for IE, like `font-family: Arial Unicode MS` you might have better luck there. Though, like I said in my answer, you may want to just use the [css triangle border hack instead](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-triangle/). I just used the unicode character because it was quicker to set up for the example.